# How to check if a polygon is on top of a linestring in JaguarDB?

Tags: database, geometry

I have two geometries one of which is polygon( (0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 0 0)) and another is linestring( 11 22, 33 44, 55 66). How can I write query to check if the polygon is on top of the linestring?

Answer (score 1):

For now you can get the center coordinates of the polygon, rotate it and the linestring, then check if the center is on the left of the linestring. It may be like:

select isonleft( rotate(center(polgon), 90, 'degrees'), rotate(lstr, 90, 'degrees') ) as ontop from tab;

To check if the polygon is strictly on top of the linestring, you will need yminpoint(polgon) instead of center() which will be available next release.